# change descriptor when renaming file linux

Tags: linux, rename, file-descriptors

I got a programm in CentOS which writes its log to a file. When I rename it, the programm still writes to it. Is there a way to change that file descriptor without restarting the programm?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give some more detail. What is this process? Is it a script? Can you do the renaming in the script/program? Why do you need to rename a file that's being written to in the first place? How exactly is this process writing to the file?

Comment: Can you do the renaming in the script/program? - No, I can't
Why do you need to rename a file that's being written to in the first place? - I urgently need to make a backup of log files, but I cannot stop the process that writes to them.

Comment: Please _[edit]_ your post to add new info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. This is still unclear. If you need a backup, just copy the file somewhere else, no need to stop anything. If you rename it, how is the process still writing to it? Is this a named pipe? A hard link? We can't help you unless you add more details (by [edit]ing your question).

Comment: @terdon Sorry, I don't understand what is unclear. Somehow the process still writes to a file even though I've renamed it. I need to create a backup out of that log file and empty that log file.

Comment: You have only now mentioned that you need to delete the file. You have not explained why a simple `mv logfile logfile.bak` is not enough. Are you saying the process will keep writing to `logfile.bak`? That is not possible as far as I know. It will simply recreate `logfile` and keep writing to that. If all this is not true, you need to tell us exactly what process and what file system and give a reproducible example because you describe something that is extremely strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somehow the process still writes to a file even though I've renamed it.

This is called *normal operation of the operating system*.  Once the file is opened, it doesn't matter one whit to the process(es) with the open file descriptor what name(s) the file has, or even whether the file has a name at all.

Simply put, your program's logging scheme (if that is really what it is) is sophomoric.  You're experiencing exactly *why* it is sophomoric.  This file will grow and grow forever, as long as the program generating the log keeps running, until it has consumed all of the disc space available to the user it is running as.  (Heaven help you if your program is running as the superuser.)  If one unlinks the file, the program continues to eat disc space indefinitely, because the file continues to exist on disc without a name until its last open file descriptor is closed.  And it's not possible to rotate the log file or reset the file position of the open file descriptor from outside of the program itself.  So even truncation doesn't work, because the program continues writing from its last position, as [this person discovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/).

There's nothing that you can do now, absent attaching a debugger, until the program ends.  Next time, tell your program to log to its standard error or standard output, if that is at all possible.  Then send that standard error/standard output through a pipe to a program such as [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html), [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html), [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html), [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html), [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8), or [`cyclog`](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh.html).  You'll get a size-capped, automatically cycled, rotateable-on-demand set of log files.

An inferior course of action next time is to open the file in append mode.  You'll have to muck about with copying and truncating the log, because rotating by renaming the file still won't work; and of course this has the potential to lose log data, as the `logrotate` manual page says, because of the window of opportunity between making the copy and truncating the file.  The aforementioned logging tools, in contrast, don't lose log data at unpredictable points because of log rotation by the likes of `newsyslog` or `logrotate` (which one doesn't need and doesn't use).  Use them in conjunction with a process supervisor that keeps the pipe open, and they don't even lose log data when one reconfigures and re-starts the logger on the fly.